# Bug Item of RecyclerView stuck (keeping ripple) when touch and scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, data-binding, android-motionlayout

**Issue Description:**

I'm facing an issue with the RecyclerView in my Android application. When I touch an item in the RecyclerView, the ripple effect is triggered as expected. However, after releasing the touch and scrolling the list, the ripple effect remains stuck (keeps showing) on that item and doesn't disappear as intended.
[image]
**XML code for the item layout:**

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"\>

    <!-- Define data variables here -->
    
    <!-- UI components for the item -->
    <!-- ... -->
    
    <!-- View for the ripple effect -->
    <View
        android:onClick="@{() -> itemStoreListener.clickItem(itemStore)}"
        android:id="@+id/viewClick"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgBackground"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgBackground"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_12dp" />
```

**Steps Tried:**

I tried using longClickAble="false" and focusAble="false" in the item's XML, but the ripple effect still persists after scrolling the list.

I attempted to call notifyItemChange(layoutPosition) when touching an item in the RecyclerView, but the ripple effect remains visible after releasing the touch and scrolling the list.

**Additional Information:**

I'm using MotionLayout to add motion effects to the page that contains the RecyclerView.

I have checked and found no errors related to touch event handling in the adapter.

I would appreciate any help and suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

**Updated: 27/07/2023**

The cause of the bug is Motion Layout, I am using touchAnchorId with this recycler. Delete it and the error should go away.